# How can I give Android Studio update permissions?

Tags: android-studio, flatpak

I installed Android Studio using flatpak.

But now I cannot update it because of write permissions. How can I give write permissions to it?

I know about Flatseal but don't know what to turn off or on.

Comment: Flatpaks, AppImages, and Snaps are not built to be updated by their own software, the only real way to 'update' one of those is to install the newer flatpak.  I don't know of a way to do that with Flatseal or any other tools currently, have you checked to see if there's an updated flatpak for installation?

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains Toolbox just solved my problem. I install the JetBrains Toolbox from the official site and extracted it in /opt directory. Now I just need to go to the opt/JetBrains/... and run the JetBrains sh file. And it runs on root mode afterwards, from there I can install/update any JetBrains IDE.